# How do gear and Vigor upgrades that cause Vigor effects to chain work?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

The 'Storm' hat gear is described as:

"*Killing with Devil's Kiss, Shock Jockey, or Bucking Bronco causes effects to chain to nearby enemies.*" 
[image]

The '[Bronco Aid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q69mJ.jpg)', Bucking Bronco upgrade ("*Adds ability to chain floating effect from one enemy to another*") and 'Shock Chain', Shock Jockey upgrade also causes Vigor effects to chain.

For the above-mentioned gear and Vigor upgrades:

- Up to how many enemies will the Vigor effects chain to?
- Is enemy distance a factor? What range should an enemy be in so that the effects will chain to them?
- Are certain enemies immune to the chain effect?
- Will an effect chain to a non-hostile NPC?
- How do they stack with each other? (e.g. if one has equipped the 'Storm' hat and has one of the above-mentioned Vigor upgrades)

EDIT:

An [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/112624/4797) seems to suggest that the 'chain' effects are actually '[area of effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_effect)', instead of 'chain', since there appears to be no 'chain' limit, but a distance limit. This is like [Skyrim's "Chain" Lightning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/61258/4797), which is actually area of effect, instead of 'chain'. Can anyone who has experience or has done testing with this, expound more on the supposed 'chain' effects of these gear and Vigor?

Comment: Let me know or suggest an edit if I've missed a gear or Vigor upgrade that causes Vigor effects to chain.

Comment: The gear "Overkill" causes the Shock Jokey 'chain' effect.

Comment: The 'Overkill' gear seems to be 'area of effect', rather than 'chain', [from its description](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Overkill) ("*killing with excessive damage stuns nearby enemies*").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a limit to the number of enemies that will be effected, although there is a distance limit.  I would say the distance is roughly 3-5 "shoulder widths" of the standard human enemy.  It's relatively similar to the radius of a trap created from that particular Vigor.

The effect is the same as the base Vigor effect, so if an enemy is immune to the effect, they will not be effected.

There doesn't appear to be any stacking bonus from having multiple effects of this type equipped simultaneously.  Overkill + Storm was the combo I tested, and I didn't see any difference between the effects.

They *will* chain to non-hostile NPCs, and as jmfsg points out, there are times when you're in a mixed fight with armed allies and enemies - this can lead to a bad situation if you turn your allies hostile.  In situations where there are "neutral" NPCs (ie, peaceful civilians) or charmed/friendly automatons, the only effect is damaging or destroying them.

Comment: @jmfsg, ooh, yeah, I forgot about those guys.  Not Good.

Comment: @agent86 Are they actually area-of-effect instead of 'chain'? (Since there is no 'chain' limit, but a distance limit - like [Skyrim's "Chain" Lightning](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/61258/4797))

Comment: @galacticninja, yeah, I'd say they're more properly area of effect.  I haven't tested extensively what happens if you chain the chain, so to speak...  if you kill, and then get a kill with the chained effect, it may chain *again*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can chain infinitely with the vigors, my personal favorite is bronco on 1999 mode. I can take out a whole room of baddies by putting a few up in the air, volley gun one-shot or rpg, and then chain the effect from enemy to enemy.  After I got the 'bronco aid' I ditched the storm hat for ammo cap since I noticed no new effects.